# How to reduce variance in Monte Carlo using Control Variates when spot prices are decreasing?

Tags: options, option-pricing, monte-carlo, variance

I'm trying to use the Control Variates technique to reduce the variance of the estimate obtained from a Monte Carlo simulation for option pricing. As suggested in the book by Glasserman I'm using this control variate estimator

$$ \text{"option price at time 0"} \approx \hat Y = \frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i $$

where $Z_i$ are the components of the vector $Z = Y-\theta(X-\mathbb E[X])$, with $V=e^{-rT}(S(T)-K)$ vector of discounted payoffs (outputs of the Monte Carlo simulation), $X=e^{-rT}S(T)$ and $S(T)$ is the vector of spot prices at expiry time $T$ generated in the simulation, $\theta$ is a constant chosen to be the minimzer of $Z$ that is $\theta=\dfrac{\text{cov}(Y,X)}{\text{var}(X)}$. Finally, under the risk-neutral measure $X$ is a martingale and $\mathbb E[X]=S(0)$.

The last identity comes from the previous book "the absence of arbitrage is essentially equivalent to the requirement that appropriately discounted asset prices be martingales. Any martingale with a known initial value provides a potential control variate precisely because its expectation at any future time is its initial value".

What I don't get is the basic assumption $\mathbb E[S(T)]=e^{rT}S(0)$ which implies that the spot prices will keep growing in the future ($e^{rT}$ is strictly bigger than $1$).

In the example I'm working on - option under the Schwartz model $dS = \alpha(\mu-\log S)Sdt + \sigma S dW$ - the initial spot price is $S(0)=22.93$ but almost all (98.5%) the spot prices $S(T)$ computed with the Monte Carlo simulation are smaller than $S(0)$, hence $\mathbb E[S(T)]<e^{rT}S(0)$ and $\hat Y$ is a bad estimator of the option price (exact solution is 2.08 while the control variate estimator is 5.88).

So I guess that a different $X$ has to be chosen, any idea on possible candidates?

---

This is the output of the Matlab code used to compute the price `V` of the option at time 0 using Monte Carlo simulations with the suggestion by jherek

```
V_MC_standard = 0.070141, std = 0.000144
V_MC_controlv = 0.070216, std = 0.000074
```

and this is the code

```
S0 = 1; % spot price at time 0
K = 1; % strike prices
T = 1/2; % expiry time
r = .1; % risk-free interest rate
alpha = .2;
sigma = 0.4;
mu = 0.3;

%% Standard Monte Carlo
N = 1e6;
X = log(S0)*exp(-alpha*T) + (mu-sigma^2/2/alpha-(mu-r)/alpha)*(1-exp(-alpha*T)) + sigma*sqrt(1-exp(-2*alpha*T))/sqrt(2*alpha)*randn(N,1);
S = exp(X);
V = exp( -r*T ) * max(0,S-K);
V0 = mean(V);
fprintf('V_MC_standard = %f, std = %f\n' , V0 , std(V)/sqrt(N) );

%% Control Variates
VC = exp(-r*T)*S; % mean(VC) == S0
C = cov(V,VC); % the covariance matrix
theta = C(1,2)/C(2,2); % the optimal theta
F = exp( exp(-alpha*T)*log(S0) + (mu-sigma^2/2/alpha-(mu-r)/alpha)*(1-exp(-alpha*T)) + sigma^2/4/alpha*(1-exp(-2*alpha*T)) );
V = V-theta*(VC-exp(-r*T)*F);
V0 = mean(V); % Controlled Monte Carlo estimate of the option value
fprintf('V_MC_controlv = %f, std = %f\n' , V0 , std(V)/sqrt(N))
```

Comment: Just a minor comment: I believe you are using [this](https://i.imgur.com/jukkFkr.png) equation to compute `X` but I suspect the normal should be $N(0, T)$. What do you think? Then when you compute the `mean`, that term vanishes since its expected value is zero.

Comment: @rvignolo The explicit formula for the $\log$ of the spot price is
$$ X_t = X_0 e^{-\alpha t} + \Big(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2\alpha}-\lambda\Big)(1-e^{-\alpha t}) + \sigma e^{-\alpha t} \underbrace{\int_0^t e^{\alpha s} dW_s}_{I} $$
$I$ is the "sum" of independent Normals so it is also Normal with mean the sum of the means, ie $0$, and variance the sum of the variances, ie $\displaystyle\int_0^t e^{2\alpha s}ds=\frac{e^{2\alpha t}-1}{2\alpha}$ hence

Comment: hence $I \sim N\Bigg(0,\dfrac{e^{2\alpha t}-1}{2\alpha}\Bigg) \sim \sqrt{\dfrac{e^{2\alpha t}-1}{2\alpha}} N(0,1)$ and
$$ \sigma e^{-\alpha t} I \sim \sigma \sqrt{e^{-2\alpha t}\frac{e^{2\alpha t}-1}{2\alpha}} N(0,1) \sim \sigma\sqrt{\dfrac{1-e^{-2\alpha t}}{2\alpha}} N(0,1)$$

Comment: Obvious first place to look is the solution of the PDE...did you derive it yourself or get one from a *Numerical Recipes* sort of text?

Comment: @Chris The solution is derived by Schwartz himself at page 5 here https://sci-hub.st/10.1111/j.1540-6261.1997.tb02721.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the assumptions here are wrong.
The issue here is that $$S_0 \neq e^{-rT} E[S],$$
but $$F = E[S].$$

And thus Z should be `Z=V-theta*(VC-exp(-rT)*F)`. If you output `mean(VC)` it's very clear.

It suggests that the choice of parameters for the Schwartz model are not consistent with the interest rate r, unless a non-zero convenience yield is expected.

Comment: Thank you for help, I tried your formula for `Z` but then `mean(Z)` is exactly equal (up to 10 decimal digits) to `V_exact`, and by lowering the number of simulations `N` to 1e1 the precision increases (equal up to 14 decimal digits). It seems quite strange, is this how it is supposed to work?

Comment: The formula $S_0 = e^{-rT} E[S]$ is written in the book by Glasserman look here https://i.imgur.com/zlBFzTB.png

Comment: The formula $F=S_0 e^{rT}$ implies that spot prices increase in time, but usng the parameters estmated from market data, they decrease if $T$ is low, increase if $T$ is higher, I think this is due to the fact that the market data that I use to estimate the parameters don't always increase, they are the first 200 monthly oil spot prices downloadable from here https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/pet_pri_spt_s1_m.htm (sheet Data 1)

Comment: The equality is expected since the control variate is essentially the same as the payoff (minus a constant). If you were pricing an option instead of a forward contract, you would see a difference.

Comment: I think there is a confusion with the market price of risk (usually referred to by $\lambda$ in Schwartz paper)  here. In particular, it is set to $\mu-r$ in the calculation of $F$. There is no reason why it should be so.

Comment: Regarding Glassermann comment, there must be some preliminary conditions on the asset, not specified in this paragraph. An asset that pays dividends will not obey this equation (see Shreve Stochastic Calculus for Finance II, 5.5, p. 234). Similarly, a convenience yield is an additional cost of the commodity related to storage that must be taken into account. Now if you assume convenience yield = 0, then you must adjust the $\lambda$ such that the equation $F=S_0 e^{rT}$ holds (i.e. calibrate the model). The idea of Schwartz is however that you calibrate F directly against the market futures.

Comment: Thank you for support. There might be a problem, because I should price an option. In my course notes it is written that "The forward contract with price at delivery of $F(S,T)$, where $S=S_0$ and $T$ is the expiry time, is equivalent to having an option with $\text{payoff}(S_T)=S_T-K$, with $K=F(S,T)$, and that $V(S,t)=e^{-r(T-t)}F(S,t)$ (look here https://i.imgur.com/q1k9YAH.png). I'm struggling to understand all of this, but I'm quite sure that I'm pricing that option, am I doing it in a wrong way?

Comment: I'm using $\lambda=\mu-r$ since it is written so in the notes https://i.imgur.com/TRFnPWT.png, then prof. says that we have to use forward prices to estimate the parameters $\mu$ and $\alpha$, I think this is the same as what you said before "The idea of Schwartz is however that you calibrate F directly against the market futures"

Comment: Yes my asset is assumed to not pay dividend, and there are no costs related to storage, because we did not study such things in my course. I will add to the main question the code that I use to estimate the parameters, do you mean that I should change this in order to properly calibrate F? Thank you

Comment: As you struggle with what is a forward, and what is an option, I would advise to read some books around option pricing before asking all of this on stackexchange. The usuals are Hull "options futures,...", or Paul Wilmott on Quantitative Finance. You could also check out the first chapter of my own book https://jherekhealy.github.io

Comment: The important things to know to solve this problem are that an option give us the right but not the obligation to exercise it, while a forward oblige us to buy/sell the underlying. From this follow that the buyer of an option pays a fee/premium for this right, while there is no cost in entering a forward contract.

Comment: As others, I think your change of measure / market price of risk is not consistent. If you wanted your asset to truly grow at the risk free rate (under Q), you would need to solve for a parameter, say, theta, such that E(S(T))=S(0)*exp(rT). I think your setup does not support this.

Comment: @jherek I studied more in the past few days, and using your suggestion now the control variates method works fine (see updated code in the question) since the variance is reduced, thank you! May I ask another suggestion about how to compute the exact price of the option at time 0? Looking at the output, the exact price is close to 0.0702. I tried with `max(F-K)*exp(-r*T)` but the result is negative hence not correct, do you know how to compute it? Again thank you very much

Comment: The result can not be negative, you must have made a mistake somewhere, perhaps max(F-K,0)*...

Comment: I agree that the result cannot be negative. The approximated option price computed by Monte Carlo is about 0.0702 (with standard deviation 0.000144) hence we should expect that also the exact option price is about 0.0702, right? I tried with `max(0,F-K)` but it is equal to 0, so it is not correct I guess

Comment: I noticed a strange thing, that is if I reduce K by 0.1 each time (the values of the other parameters are the ones written in the code above), then theta grows (and becomes 1 when K<0.4) and the option value computed using `exp(-rT) * (F-K)` approaches the value computed by monte carlo. I don't understand why this happens